# Groupby for nestedlists

Tags: python, list

I have a list `[[1,20],[1,30],[2,30],[2,50],[3,60], [1,20]]`. If the first elements on the nested list is same as previous, i should remove that(not removing the duplicates on the list). In this case, i should get as `[[1,20],[2,30],[3,60],[1,20]]`.

I am using itemgetter and groupby and have written this:

```
[x[0] for x in groupby(testlist, itemgetter(0))]
```

The above code outputs only the first element as [1, 2, 3, 1]. I want this to be in the same nested list format as `[[1,20],[2,30],[3,60],[1,20]]`. How can i do this in-place on the same list, 'testlist'. Is there any better way to achieve this than simply iterating the whole list again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only showing the keys. [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) returns a tuple of keys and groups. You need the first item in the groups:

```
print [next(g) for k, g in groupby(i, itemgetter(0))]
# # [[1, 20], [2, 30], [3, 60], [1, 20]]
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do on the same list in-place(rather than assigning it to the same list again)

Comment: @HighlyCurious Not sure I understand what you mean by *rather than assigning it to the same list again*. In any case, you can do a full-slice assignment: `lst[:] = ...`

Comment: You could also use `next(g)` instead of `list(g)[0]`.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye i m sorry, that was not clear. What I meant was to sort it in-place. Here i wanted to know if this filtering can be applied on the list 'i' in [list(g)[0] for k, g in groupby(i, itemgetter(0))] instead of doing i = [list(g)[0] for k, g in groupby(i, itemgetter(0))]

Comment: @tobias_k I knew something was fishy about the initial list conversion. Thanks.